# Two actions for one UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I have an `edit button`, that I obtained through `self.editButtonItem` and I have set it as `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`, such that when it is pressed, a `UITableView` begins editing and it turns into a `"Done" button`. When pressed again the view stops editing and the button returns to its normal state.
I would also like an `"add" button` to turn into a `"Clear" button` with a different action linked to it when the edit button is pressed.
(Much like in the `iPhone` `"Phone" app's favourites tab,` just that the plus button turns into a clear button when the Edit button is pressed).

I would really like to obtain the `edit action` and style etc in this way (`self.editButtonItem`), but I would also like to have an extra selector linked to the `edit button`.

**How should I go about doing this?** I have tried to create a category for `UIBarButtonItem`, but I don't really know what I should do with that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a button whose title can change, you can do the following:

Define an ivar for the button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *_btnAddClear;
```

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
_btnAddClear = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(addClearAction:)];
_btnAddClear.possibleTitles = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Add", @"Clear", nil];
```

Since you want this button's title to change when the Edit/Done button is tapped, you can add code like the following:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    _btnAddClear.title = editing ? @"Clear" : @"All";
}
```

And lastly, the button handler:

```
- (void)addClearAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)button {
    if (self.editing) {
        // perform "clear" action
    } else {
        // perform "add" action
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give tag of `UIBarButton` such like **101;**

and in BarButton Method write  following

```
-(void)barButtonMethod
{
    UIBarButtonItem * myButton = (UIBarButtonItem *) sender;

    if(sender.tag == 101)
    {
         yourBtn.tag = 102;

         // Write Your first action method such like

         [self ActionMethod1];
    }
    else
    {
         yourBtn.tag = 101; 

        // Write Your second action method such like

         [self ActionMethod2]; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a new action for the editButtonItem.

There is a property that tracks if the UIViewController is in editing state.

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isEditing) BOOL editing
```

In order to do what you want, you can implement the following method in your UITableViewController:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated]        
    //Do your thing
}
```